# Salesforce email trigger

Tags: salesforce

Hello please help my friend to write code, his task is

No contacts should be inserted or updated if email does not has " com. Net" email is a custom filed on contact. I want you to do it by trigger this trigger should only fire on insert and change of email

[code he write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv2dd.jpg)

Code he write :

```
trigger InsertedUpdated on Contact (before insert,before update){
  for(contact con:trigger.new)

      if( con.Email=='xyz@gmail.com'){
            // con.Last='.com /.net';
     }

       for( contact con:trigger.new ){
       if(con.Email!=trigger.Oldmap.get(con.Id).Email || con.Email!=trigger.Oldmap.get(con.Id).Email){
           if( con.Email=='xyz@gmail.com' ){
            con.adderror('Email does not correct ');
           }

       x

       }
       }
```

}

Comment: Please insert the code as text, formatted as code, not as picture.

Comment: done please check

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use a trigger? A validation rule seems better suited to this use case, and will provide friendlier errors when violated.
You can find information on using regex in a validation rule [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329165&type=1&mode=1)
If it is absolutely necessary to use a trigger, [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092GXIAY) has an example of how to write a regex in apex.